# Unity3d animation returning back to idle state

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't figure out best way to write simple code. All I need to play animation on each event(tap for example) and stop on animation end.

So I have object with two animation: idle and active. And bool variable "state". 
if state==false then idle animation will be run.
if state==true then active animation will be run.
On tap I am changing status to true.

Problems:

- if state changed once then value is true and "active" animation will not be played anymore.

If I will somehow catch end of animation(with event or with checking status in update) and change state back to false

- animation should be finish to be started again.
- architecture become very hard(in case if I have several objects like this it will be really mess)

Comment: Please share some code like how you using aniumation clips etc

Comment: Are you using an Animator component, or some kind of custom solution for managing animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Mecanim, you can use a [trigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) type parameter instead of boolean.